# pass data to modal in vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-resource

I created a vue app in cli. And I have a List component file:

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
 <h1 class="text-center">List member</h1>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">ID</th>
      <th class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th class="text-center">Birthday</th>
      <th class="text-center">Score</th>
      <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="person in people">
      <td class="text-center">{{ person.id }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ person.name }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ person.birthday }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{ person.score }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <b-btn v-b-modal.my-modal>Edit</b-btn>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

And I have modal component in this file:

```
    <!-- Modal Component -->
    <b-modal id="my-modal" ref="modal" title="Edit profile" @ok="handleOk" 
       @shown="clearName">
      <form @submit.stop.prevent="handleSubmit">
        <b-form-input type="text">{{ person.name }}</b-form-input>
        <br>
        <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
        <br>
        <b-form-input type="text"></b-form-input>
      </form>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

How can I pass data in a row (person) to modal when I click Edit button?
Thanks

Comment: What is `<b-btn v-b-modal.my-modal>Edit</b-btn>`?

Comment: It's <button> </button>, I used bootstrap vue, so it is <b-btn>

Comment: So both snippets you showed are in the same .vue file?

Comment: Yes, I put them on same file

Answer (score 0):

in my case i fixed this with bootstrap modal and JQuery

1- HTML Modal

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="document-details-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="document-details-modal" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">modal-title-details-document</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-title</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-title"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-source-info</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-source-info"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-author</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-author"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-language</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-language"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-description</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-description"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-3">
                            <div class="label">label-library-file-comments</div>
                            <span id="document-details-document-comments"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2- Vuejs Call

```
<a href="#"><i class="bi bi-info-circle" v-on:click="setDocumentDetails(libraryItem)"></i></a>
```

3- Vuejs Funcation

```
            setDocumentDetails: function (libraryItem) {
               
                                $('#document-details-document-title').text(libraryItem.Title);
                                $('#document-details-document-description').text(libraryItem.Description);
                                $('#document-details-document-source-info').text(libraryItem.SourceInfo);
                                $('#document-details-document-comments').text(libraryItem.Comments);
                                $('#document-details-document-author').text(libraryItem.Author);
                                $('#document-details-document-language').text(libraryItem.Language);
                                $('#document-details-modal').modal('show');

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure this will work, and even less sure that this is elegant, but if they are in the same file, you could try having a `currentPerson` property that you set to `person` when this button is clicked. Like

```
<b-btn @click="currentPerson = person" v-b-modal.my-modal>Edit</b-btn>
```

and then just use `{{currentPerson.name}}` in the modal.