# standalone Vue js: pass data to modal component

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, components

Hello I have question regarding passing data to modal component using standalone Vue js.
The flow is user click on the button that 'select a country' and modal opens up and user can select a country with slider. once user clicked on confirm, modal closes.

I've tried using for loops to pass the data into modal components but it also prints out many buttons.

Thank you for your help

I have a HTML code that user can select a countries

```
<div class="select_championship_country" @click="enableCountryModal()">Select a country</div>
<modal v-if="showCountryModal" @close="showModal = false"></modal>
```

Here is the modal component code:

```
 <!-- countury modal -->
        <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
            <transition name="modal">
              <div class="modal-mask">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                  <div class="modal-container">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <slot name="header">
                        select the country you want to support
                      </slot>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <slot name="body">
                        <div class="country_select_carousel">
                          <div class="countrySlide">
                            <!-- <img :src="imgUrl + '/flags/' + item.imgName"> -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </slot>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <slot name="footer">
                        <div class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                          confirm
                        </div>
                      </slot>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </transition>
          </script>
```

This is country data array object and modal component

```
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: {
    modal: {
      template: '#modal-template',
    }
  },
  data: {
    country_carousel_data: [
      {
        imgName: 'brasil.svg',
        desc: 'brasil',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'canada.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'egypt.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'france.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'germany.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'india.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'poland.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'portugal.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'tunisia.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'turkey.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'uk.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
      {
        imgName: 'usa.svg',
        desc: '',
      },
    ],
 }
```

Comment: may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325570/pass-data-to-modal-in-vue-js-app/73894540#73894540) help, in may case it was fine

Answer (score 0):

Where did you use the for-loop in your modal template? I do not see any v-for.

Your  should not be inside for loop. I am guessing since you mentioned it prints out many buttons you had that inside the for loop. the v-for should be on the  tag like below

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
            <transition name="modal">
              <div class="modal-mask">
                <div class="modal-wrapper">
                  <div class="modal-container">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <slot name="header">
                        select the country you want to support
                      </slot>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <slot name="body">
                        <div class="country_select_carousel">
                          <div class="countrySlide">

                           <img v-for="item in country_carousel_data" :src="imgUrl + '/flags/' + item.imgName"> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </slot>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <slot name="footer">
                        <div class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                          confirm
                        </div>
                      </slot>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </transition>
          </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was trying to pass the props value using function(item) when it was clicked.  That is why it was printed out many buttons. I found the way how to pass the value as props read through documentation. 
here is my codepen [link](https://codepen.io/MachoBoy/pen/LrEqOK)